# Loading data from a csv file and display in list of tuples

Tags: python, list, function, csv, tuples

Does anyone have an idea on how to write a function `loading_values(csvfilename)` that takes a string corresponding to the name of the data file and returns a list of tuples containing the subset name (as a string) and a list of floating point data values.
the result should be something like this when the function is called

```
>>> stat = loading_values(`statistics.csv`)
>>> stat
     [('Pressure', [31.52, 20.3, ..., 27.90, 59.58]),
      ('Temp', [97.81, 57.99, ..., 57.80, 64.64]),
      ('Range', [79.10, 42.83, ..., 68.84, 26.88])]
```

for now my code returns separate tuples for each subheading not joined by (,)

```
f=open('statistics.csv', 'r')
for c in f:
    numbers = c.split(',')
    numbers = (numbers[0], (numbers[1::]))

[('Pressure', [31.52, 20.3, ..., 27.90, 59.58])
 ('Temp', [97.81, 57.99, ..., 57.80, 64.64])
 ('Range', [79.10, 42.83, ..., 68.84, 26.88])]
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `csv` module?

Comment: I have yeah but since I have to perform a number of stat functions (like mean, count, max, min and the like) it would be easier without the csv module, or at least that's what I was told

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel unless you want to (and even then only as an excersise)

Comment: @kattoch  
How you want the output to be?

Comment: it should be displayed like stat in the first block of code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
def loading_values(csvfile):
    f=open(csvfile, 'r')
    results = []
    for line in f:
        numbers = list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), line.split(',')))
        results.append((numbers[0], numbers[1:]))

    return results

print loading_values(`statistics.csv`)
```

or you may use [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
with open('statistics.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    results = map( lambda x: (x[0],x[1:]), reader)
```

Comment: not really familiar with using map(lambda x: ) but i'm getting this when I run it

    <map object at 0x030C4EF0>

Comment: you are using python 3? print `list(results)`

Comment: yes I'm using 3.4, and yeah it worked thank you so much for the help, now I just have to research map(lambda... to get an understanding on how it's working

Comment: great, check this [Lambda, filter, reduce and map](http://www.python-course.eu/lambda.php)

Comment: sorry just a follow up on this, when I load the actual data from the csv file there are white spaces at the end of each subset, in my old code I used c.strip() but it's not working now with the new code, any suggestion?

Comment: try:  `results = map( lambda x: tuple([y.strip() for y in x.split(',')]), f)` or you may ask it as a new question

Comment: @kattoch you can't just drop the answer acceptance cause you found a new unrelated issue. just ask a new question and I will be happy to answer it

Comment: actually I just realized the output is a bit different than stat above it's like this
[('Pressure', 31.52, 20.3, ..., 27.90, 59.58)
 ('Temp', 97.81, 57.99, ..., 57.80, 64.64)
 ('Range', 79.10, 42.83, ..., 68.84, 26.88)]
instead of 
[('Pressure', [31.52, 20.3, ..., 27.90, 59.58]),
      ('Temp', [97.81, 57.99, ..., 57.80, 64.64]),
      ('Range', [79.10, 42.83, ..., 68.84, 26.88])]

Comment: I'm sorry for that but just double-checked and that code doesn't give me the wanted output even before the .strip() adjustment

Comment: try the updated code, it gives  ( e1, [e2,e3,e4 ... ])

Comment: it does yeah but only when you call the generator outside the function and it should be returned from the function itself

Comment: use it like that "results = list(loading_values(`statistics.csv`))" than continue using `results`.

Comment: @kattoch if you dont like a generator I will change it to a normal function.

Comment: it's not that I don't like it and thank you so much for all the help, but the function I'm after should automatically returns that result without a generator because it would be used a lot and for different files too

Comment: updated, try the new code. I think a generator will do better for huge csv files.

Comment: it's perfect! thank you heaps! it's not gonna be huge csv files still only few subsets in each file but will need to call this function many times and get that output to check the data
Thanks again